# horner data structure

Tags: java

Hi
I have a question that how can we use Horner data structure for showing a polynomial which is like " `x^100+1`" ?

> for example for above polynomial we
>   need array of size 101 which its index
>   shows the power of this polynomial for
>   example for array[100]=1 and array[0]
>   = 1 and unfortunately all the other indexes are 0 !!! but there is another
>   way which is difference from this and
>   helps to show a polynomial in a little
>   array !!! and I want to know that way

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?  Do you understand how the Horner method works?  What have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: for example for above polynomial we need array of size 101 which its index shows the power of this polynomial for example for array[100]=1 and array[0] = 1 and unfortunately all the other indexes are 0 !!! but there is another way which is difference from this and helps to show a polynomial in a little array !!! and I want to know that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horner scheme (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme) is another way to represent a polynomial but needs the same amount of information (same array size) since the information content is identical. The only difference is the ordering when we calculate the polynomial.

```
p(x) = (...((a[n] * x + a[n-1]) * x + a[n-2]) ...) * x + a[0]
```

In your example we would again have a[100] = 1, a[0] = 1 and the rest zero.

In this case the code to calculate the polynomial would be

```
result = a[n];
for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--) {
    result = result * x + a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general for polynomials of form

```
A * x^n + B * x^n-1 + ....
```

you would just need to know n and store (A, B, ...) for which you could you an array or List. For representation, all you need is n and this list.
I'm not sure if you are interested in evaluation, but it'll be something like

```
ArrayList<int> list = new ArrayList<int>();
```

fill list with A, B,...

```
int result;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    result+= list.get(i) * Math.pow(valueOfX, n-i);
```